# Pushing JAX-B object over network

Tags: java, xml, rest, jaxb, jersey

I have some interface description in text describing a RESTful webserver. I also have JAX-B annotated objects that I want to push and receive from that interface.

I'm not sure how much support for such a task is already implemented. There is some Jersey thing around, but is that still up to date?

Do I have to define a target URL, open a stream, serialize the xml object (maybe turning it into a string first?), and then write it to the stream?

Or is there some magic method that only expects a URL and the JAX-B object and maybe if I want to PUT,DELETE,POST or GET it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**JAX-RS** is what you want to use in this case and Jersey is the reference implementation.  JAXB is the default binding layer for JAX-RS.  Below is an example of a RESTful service that supports `PUT`, `DELETE`, `POST`, and `GET`:

```
package org.example;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Stateless
@LocalBean
@Path("/customers")
public class CustomerService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="CustomerService",
                        type=PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public void create(Customer customer) {
        entityManager.persist(customer);
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Path("{id}")
    public Customer read(@PathParam("id") long id) {
        return entityManager.find(Customer.class, id);
    }

    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public void update(Customer customer) {
        entityManager.merge(customer);
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("{id}")
    public void delete(@PathParam("id") long id) {
        Customer customer = read(id);
        if(null != customer) {
            entityManager.remove(customer);
        }
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Path("findCustomersByCity/{city}")
    public List<Customer> findCustomersByCity(@PathParam("city") String city) {
        Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("findCustomersByCity");
        query.setParameter("city", city);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

}
```

Below are links to the full example:

- [Part 1 - Data Model](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-15.html)
- [Part 2 - JPA](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-25.html)
- [Part 3 - JAXB (using MOXy)](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-35.html)
- [Part 4 - RESTful Service (using an EJB session bean)](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-45.html)

Comment: Great answer, beat me to it :)